# Command Prompt vs System() in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, imagemagick, command-prompt

I'm attempting to use imagemagick to combine a bunch of .ppm files I create in Visual Studio, each a piece of an animation.

When I complete the program and get all of the output*.ppm files, I can go to my command prompt and say im-convert -delay 80 output*.ppm final.gif, it works perfect and creates the gif.  However, using a system("im-convert -delay 80 output*.ppm final.gif"); call in my code, the result says that im-convert is not a recognized command.

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.  Does visual studio not use the same command prompt?  Do I need to include the .dll for imagemagick somewhere else where that command prompt will find it?

Thanks :)

Comment: why not use the imagemagik library directly?

Comment: I was going to originally, but it seemed silly to when it takes literally one system call to do what I want.  Likewise, I could just do it in my command prompt, but I don't want to have to redo it every time I make a new animation :/

Comment: You'll need to provide the full path to im-convert.exe or set the default working directory of your program correctly.  The "silly" part of your comment stops being funny when anything goes wrong and it just stops working without you being able to diagnose why.